# Acessing unexported function `nat.string`

Tags: go

I want to convert a `big.Int` to simple base32. Not the standard base32 stuff like the *RFC 4648* implemented by `base32` nor *zBase32* nor *Crockford* I want just simple normal 5-bits per character 0-9A-V character set.

I am aware of the `base32` package and it does not do what I want - it builds the result in a standard base 32 number with padding and stuff I don't want. Certainly I could use it and tear off the trailing "=" characters and hack what remains but that just seems like a brutal solution.

There is a `big.SetString(string, base)` that can parse a base32 number in string form but there is no reverse - which is what I am really looking for, a `big.GetString(base)` like the Java `BigInteger.toString(int base)`.

There is, however, a `nat.string` which does **exactly** what I want. How can I gain access to it?

Is there a way I could manually extend `big` to implement `big.GetString(base)` which trivially calls `nat.string` with the correct `charset`?

Is there a way I can reach into the unexported `big.nat` which `big` uses and call `nat.string`?

Is there something else I can do?

P.S. I'd also be interested in using `nat.trailingZeroBits` - I had to write my own because I didn't realise this was already done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access unexported functions at all. You'd need to re-write at least some portion of `nat.go` in order to achieve that functionality. Some of those functions look very useful, so it may be worth [sending a feature request to the `golang-nuts` group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) asking for some of them to be exported in a future release.

You can however use [`strconv.FormatInt()`](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatInt) to do what you require.

given a `big.Int` `b` you can do:

```
strconv.FormatInt(b.Int64(), 32)
```

Full example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    i := 3286583923486565782 // Some random integer
    b := big.NewInt(int64(i))
    fmt.Println(strconv.FormatInt(b.Int64(), 32))
}
```

Produces:

> > 2r72al99uq9cm

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/YjPyt-AtIc)

Comment: Thanks but I need more than 64 bits.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the go team will ever export anything in `nat` as that is an implementation details for `big.Int`.  They may look kindly upon a request to export a `ToBase` function though from `big.Int`.

In the mean time here is a lightly tested naive base converter for you

```
func ToBase(x *big.Int, base int) string {
    if x.Sign() == 0 {
        return "0"
    }
    y := new(big.Int).Set(x)
    b := big.NewInt(int64(base))
    charset := "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    out := make([]byte, 0, 16)
    negative := false
    if y.Sign() < 0 {
        negative = true
        y.Neg(y)
    }
    digit := new(big.Int)
    for y.Sign() != 0 {
        y.DivMod(y, b, digit)
        out = append(out, charset[digit.Int64()])
    }
    if negative {
        out = append(out, '-')
    }
    // Reverse out
    for i, j := 0, len(out)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        out[i], out[j] = out[j], out[i]
    }
    return string(out)
}
```

[Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/1-fBWmM6An)

Answer (score 1):

I have posted on the go-nuts thread. They seem happy with my suggestion.

Meanwhile - my implementation of Base32 (does NOT handle sign - like `nat`)

```
// The digits
const charset string = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV"

/*
 Convert the big to base32
*/
func Base32(n big.Int) string {
    // The bytes of the number
    bytes := n.Bytes()
    nBytes := len(bytes)
    if nBytes == 0 {
        // Special case 0.
        return "0"
    }
    // How many digits will be in the string?
    nBits := nBytes * 8
    nDigits := nBits / 5
    if nBits%5 > 0 {
        nDigits += 1
    }
    // Grow the digits into an array
    digits := make([]byte, nDigits)
    digit := nDigits - 1
    // Peel off 5 bits from the array each time.
    for b, shr := nBytes-1, uint(0); b >= 0; {
        // The next lot is there.
        shrp5 := shr + 5
        // Build my bits.
        x := (bytes[b] >> shr)
        if shrp5 > 8 && b > 0 {
            of := shrp5 - 8
            // Add in some bits from the next byte too.
            x &= (1 << (8 - shr)) - 1
            x |= bytes[b-1] << (5 - of)
        }
        // Shift 5 more.
        shr = shrp5
        // Should we step to next byte?
        if shr >= 8 {
            // Next byte
            shr -= 8
            b -= 1
        }
        x &= 0x1f
        // Build my digit
        digits[digit] = charset[x]
        digit -= 1
    }
    // Skip leading zeros.
    lz := 0
    for digits[lz] == '0' {
        lz += 1
    }
    // Return the string equivalent.
    return string(digits[lz:])
}
```

Comments welcome.

Comment: Although I probably prefer the simplicity and readability of the answer provided by @nick-craig-wood , I *really* like this for the tricky bit manipulation (including shifting by using `& 0x1f`). I'm currently reading "Hacker's Delight" and therefore loving all bit-twiddly tricks. You probably know, but it would be trivial to make this function handle sign, as well as making it handle more bases than just 32. Now I'm off to do some benchmarking between your function and Nick's posted solution!

Comment: @Intermernet - That's a good book! Also check out [bit twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) and [HakMem](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/hbaker/hakmem/hakmem.html) - both awesome resources. I tried to make it base-generic but it broke, I will try again and deal with sign too. It will only do bases of powers of two. I think the performance of this one will be excellent but only because I am not doing any division or floating-point stuff. Nicks can handle any integer base of course.

Comment: Thanks for the links! Sign can be handled by just checking if `n.Sign() == -1` and, if so, whacking a `-` on the front of the string when you return. The string pre-pend is probably messy though. I too tried to make it base-agnostic and I too broke it. I may have a solution (store non power of two bases in the next largest power of two character slice) but haven't nutted out the finer details. Fun exercise!